# what is a degenerate function?

Tags: functions, terminology

Consider the functin $f(x, y)$, e.g:

\begin{align*}
f(x, y) &= (x+y)^2 \\
f(x, y) &= (x+y^2)^2 \\
f(x, y) &= (35 \sin x+y^2)^2 \\
\end{align*}

[image]

[image]

Dennis Auroux called this kind of functions "degenerate" because
then can be written as $f(u(x, y))$:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_goGnJm5sA

I am not sure what this is suppose to mean, could anyone explain?

Comment: It's a function that stalks people, or wears a big iffy raincoat, or curses like a sailor, or says the Axiom of Choice is false.

Comment: It's not very considerate to call functions degenerate. They're simply "different".

Comment: Does there even exist a non-degenerate function with this definition? After all $f(x,y)=\ln(u(x,y))$ with $u(x,y)=e^{f(x,y)}$.

Comment: Check this out: https://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Degenerate_distribution.html